# Spring boot con Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, spring, jpa, jdbc

siempre conecte con Mysql y PostgreSql sin problema, ahora trato de conectar con Oracle y no me mapea las tablas pero si hay conexion:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes poner el contenido de tu archivo `application.properties`  para verificar  lo  los parametros de base de datos que estas utilizando. Asi mismo, el java donde defines algún repositorio (los que tiene la etiqueta @Repository) En  los mensaje no encuentra ningun JPA Repository. Y de pasada el pom.xml

Comment: Hola Juan, si están aqui: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lm3AJ.png

Comment: Esto tengo en el Repository: @Repository
public interface PersonaDao extends CrudRepository<Persona, String> {

}

Comment: Utiliza en lugar del `CrudRepository` el `JpaRepository` que extiende del `CrudRepository` pero adicionalmente implementa funciones JPA. Prueba a ver como te va. Por lo demás no encuentro problema. Has el cambio y te debería funcionar.

Comment: El comentario que has puesto como respuesta eliminalo y agregalo a tu pregunta

Comment: He cambiado a JpaRepository y sigue igual, no he tenido éxito.

Comment: ¿El log del mensajes sigue siendo el mismo que muestras en tu pregunta? Raro porque tengo una aplicación con los mismo parametros que tienes pero a mí si me funciona. Voy a volver a revisar. Fíjate si el log ha cambiado en algo.

Comment: El log ha cambiado, dice que no encuentra el jar. :    The Class-Path manifest attribute in C:\Users\Edgar\.m2\repository\com\oracle\ojdbc\ojdbc8\19.3.0.0\ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/C:/Users/Edgar/.m2/repository/com/oracle/ojdbc/ojdbc8/19.3.0.0/oraclepki.jar

Comment: Entonces está trabajando, por el ojdbc8 y sus dependencias en el lib del servidor de aplicaciones. En tu POM.XML está runtime, por eso no se instalando en el server. Colocalo manualmente en el server en el directorio `lib` y reinicias. Solo erl ojdbc8.jar en este todas las clases o en el pom ponle que lo agregue al paquete de la aplicación pero por lo general los driver son compartidos. Una vez que lo coloques reinicias el server y ya la aplicación en el reinicio supongo

Comment: En mi caso utilicé el ojdbc8-12.2.0.1 para tu caso busca la version de Oracle que tienes.

Comment: Disculpa, eso es en el java Build Padth, yo uso sts?

Comment: Gracias Juan por tu ayuda, voy hacer los cambios y te comento.

Comment: Yo tambien uso el STS. Supongo que tienes un servidor tomcat. En ese servidor en el directorio donde esta instalado el tomcat existe un directorio lib. Alli coloca el `jodbc`. Ahora si lo ejecutas desde el mismo STS con el Servidor Interno del Spring debería ejecutarlo sin problemas a menos que el POM no haya descargado el jodbc8, si es así quítale por un momento el `<scope>runtime</scope>` depencia `com.oracle.ojdbc` del pom.xml de manera que lo descargue. En el dir `target` del proyecto donde pone el SNAPSHOT directio WEB-INF/lib tiens el ojdbc8 y oraclepki. Si es así primero desde el STS.

Comment: Prueba cambiar la propiedad `dll-auto` a `create` para la primera conexión y después la cambias de nuevo a update.

Comment: He realizado todo los cambios y sigue estando igual, es muy extraño lo que me sucede, el problema sigue siendo que no me escanea la tabla con el JPA, **Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 3 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.**

Comment: Les dejare por aquí la solución que me ha resultado, he colocado estas anotaciones en la cabecera del main: @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.demoes.identity","com.demoes.repository"})
@EntityScan ("com.demoes.entity"). Referencia :https://qastack.mx/programming/28664064/spring-boot-not-an-managed-type